# iOS Keyword Spotting

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, openears

I would like to implement keyword spotting for 6 words in my app. I have downloaded Openears, but the recognition accuracy is very poor (just tapping on the table returns one of the 6 predefined words). Are there any other open source alternatives to OpenEars or a way to increase the accuracy of Openears? (The 6 words I am using are in english)

Comment: You need to use your own language model for adding new words. Also in my knowledge there are no open-source library available for doing this (offline version)

Answer (score 3):

Openears is just fine, you only need to know that for keyword spotting you can not use the default configuration, you need to install [Rejecto Plugin](http://www.politepix.com/rejecto/) specifically designed for keyword spotting task.

Comment: Also, be sure to do any accuracy testing using a real device rather than the Simulator.